# Temporarily change current working directory in bash to run a command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, working-directory

I know I can use `cd` command to change my working directory in bash.

But if I do this command:

```
cd SOME_PATH && run_some_command
```

Then the working directory will be changed permanently. Is there some way to change the working directory just temporarily like this?

```
PWD=SOME_PATH run_some_command
```

Comment: why not keep it simple **cd SOME_PATH && run_some_command && cd -** the last command will take you back to the last pwd directory.

Comment: @Sahil then it can't be run in parallel

Answer (score 477, accepted):

You can run the `cd` and the executable in a subshell by enclosing the command line in a pair of parentheses:

```
(cd SOME_PATH && exec_some_command)
```

Demo:

```
$ pwd
/home/abhijit
$ (cd /tmp && pwd)  # directory changed in the subshell
/tmp 
$ pwd               # parent shell's pwd is still the same
/home/abhijit
```

Comment: That sort of invalidates the point of using `exec`, don't you think?

Comment: @tripleee: I guess OP meant to execute any executable and not the exec.

Comment: not working in shell file

Comment: @BeC use `function` rather than `alias`.  Better two years late than never.

Comment: best answer. works with multiline wrappers as well and premature exits

Comment: I won't see the output of the command if it runs in a subshell.

Comment: worth noting: if your subshell to run the commands (in parentheses now) and that code does an "exit" (you want to stop execution), control goes back to the parent shell (the parent shell does NOT exit).  This might be a difference if you refactor your code (execution doesn't stop anymore if something bad happens in the parentheses)

Comment: Works in a bash script for me. Also, you can use `(cd /tmp && echo $(pwd))` to test the output from a script.

Comment: awesome, works! Just wish it would be a bit more descriptive syntax :/

Answer (score 188):

bash has a builtin

```
pushd SOME_PATH
run_stuff
...
...
popd
```

Comment: +1, pushd/popd is ideal for this. Just don't forget to popd before you exit.

Comment: Not necessarily a good solution if run_stuff can fail (and the script exits).  You'd be stuck in SOME_PATH.

Comment: @ron.rothmanℝℝ couldn't you just do something like `pushd PATH; (run_stuff); [[ "$?" != 0 ]] && popd; ...; popd`

Comment: In my case, if the script execution failed e.g. `git pull`, I wanted to investigate in the directory with `git log`.

Comment: What an excellent way to quickly update targets under another project while testing. Thanks!

Comment: best answer for me!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! A subshell breaks the log output!

Answer (score 43):

Something like this should work:

```
sh -c 'cd /tmp && exec pwd'
```