# command line python script run on a file in different directory

Tags: python, command-line

I have a script.py in /Users/admin/Desktop and I want to run this script on a file that is in /Users/admin//Desktop/folder/file.txt, without changing the present dir.

Question: what is the most efficient way to do that on command-line ? I am using the following commands and results are not as expected.

```
$ python script.py --script; /Users/admin/Desktop/file.txt

     raise StopIteration('because of missing file (file.txt)')

 StopIteration: because of missing file (file.txt)
```

Comment: 1) The semicolon will prematurely terminate the command. 2) You don't show your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temporarily change current working directory in bash to run a command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382141/temporarily-change-current-working-directory-in-bash-to-run-a-command)

Comment: I have 2000 lines long code!

Comment: Did you consider pass as an argument to the script the path of file.txt?

Comment: @user3698773: post only the code relevant to the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the semicolon because that will prematurely terminate the command.
2. Pass the correct path to the file to your program. You say it is `/Users/admin/Desktop/folder/file.txt`, however, your command is using `/Users/admin/Desktop/file.txt` (it's missing `folder`)

So the command should (probably) be:

```
$ python script.py --script /Users/admin/Desktop/folder/file.txt
```

If that doesn't work you will need to edit your question to show your code.