# "cd" inside "if" condition in Bash does not change the current directory after "if"

Tags: bash, if-statement, sh, cd, error-code

I am trying to do "cd" inside "if" condition in a Bash script. It stays in the same directory after "if". So I have to do "cd" outside "if" and then use $? value in if. Is there a way to avoid using this extra step? What is the shortest possible way of doing it?

See three variants of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set +e

# If I write the following:

if ! (rm -rf sim && mkdir sim && cd sim); then
    echo $0: Cannot prepare simulation directory
    exit 1
fi

# it does not change the current directory

echo $PWD

# Also, if I write the following:

if ! rm -rf sim || ! mkdir sim || ! cd sim; then
    echo $0: Cannot prepare simulation directory
    exit 1
fi

# it also does not change the current directory

echo $PWD

# In order to change the current directory, I need to write:

rm -rf sim && mkdir sim && cd sim

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo $0: Cannot prepare simulation directory
    exit 1
fi

# Now it prints .../sim

echo $PWD
cd ..

# Is it possible to write it without an additional line with $?

exit
```

Comment: It's the `( )`s, not the `if`. Parethesis create a subshell -- they fork a completely new process with its own variables, active directory, etc.

Comment: ...so this is basically the inverse of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382141/temporarily-change-current-working-directory-in-bash-to-run-a-command (where they're asking *how to do* the thing you're doing unintentionally).

Answer (score 2):

Parenthesis in bash create a subshell -- a `fork()`-ed off copy of the shell with its own environment variables, its own current directory, etc; thus, in your first attempt, the `cd` took effect only until the closing paren ended the subshell. <sub>(POSIX doesn't strictly require this subshell behavior, but it *does* require that the environment created by parenthesis have its own working directory, so `cd`'s effects will be scoped on all standard-compliant shells, whether or not that shell actually uses a `fork()` here in all circumstances).</sub>

Use curly brackets, not parenthesis, for grouping when you don't want to create a subshell. That is:

```
if ! { rm -rf sim && mkdir sim && cd sim; }; then
    echo "$0: Cannot prepare simulation directory"
    exit 1
fi
```

---

That said, your second approach *works perfectly well* (though it's unwieldy to write and not a conventional idiom).

```
bash <<'EOF'
cd /tmp
echo "Starting in $PWD"
if ! rm -rf sim || ! mkdir sim || ! cd sim; then
    echo "$0: Cannot prepare simulation directory"
    exit 1
fi
echo "Ending in $PWD"
EOF
```

...properly emits:

```
Starting in /tmp
Ending in /tmp/sim
```

Comment: Is the fork a requirement or just an implementation detail? `bash` just says the command creates a new subshell environment, changes to which are not retained after the `(...)` completes (though the working directory is part of that environment, so this is just a small nit I'm picking).

Comment: Thank you. Is curly bracket a Bash extension? Will is work in every POSIX shell?

Comment: Not an extension; baseline-POSIX.